# obtaining the list of the coordinates of each corner/vertex of a rectangle or polygon

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a [Leaflet.Rectangle](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#rectangle) in a pretty standard way:

```
  var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
  const rectangle = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1});
```

However, when I try to get the rectangle's vertices (corners) using the `getLatLngs()` method, instead of getting an array of four `lat/lng` pairs, what I get is an array with a single element. That single element is the array I was initially expecting.

The documentation hints at that possibility:

> Returns an array of the points in the path, or nested arrays of points in case of multi-polyline.

However it is not explained what a multi-polyline is and I don't get why a multi-polyline is necessary to describe the vertices of an object as a simple as a rectangle. I find that confusing.

It also means that to test if a given `lat/lng` falls within a Leaflet rectangle using the [point-in-polygon](https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon) library I have to do:

```
inside([ 1.5, 1.5 ], rectangle.getLatLngs()[0]),
```

Is there a reason for this extra level of indirection? Am I safe in picking only the first element of the array returning by `getLatLngs()` in the case of [Leaflet.Rectangle](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#rectangle) or [Leaflet.Polygon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polygon) objects?

Answer (score 0):

It's either a mistake in the doc or a provision for later ...

I can see [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.6.0/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L194) that `getLatLngs()` will always return an array for a `L.Rectangle` (Rectangle is a Polyline)

So, for now, you are safe using `rectangle.getLatLngs()[0]`

Note that there is a mention to [multi-polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline-l-polyline) (and [multi-polygone](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polygon-l-polygon)) in the doc.